# operation not permitted on files under usr bin

Tags: macos, permissions, root, rename, openssl

I'm on OSX El Captain and I would like to rename the file "`usr/bin/openssl`" into "`usr/bin/openssl_old`" (*cause I want to update openssl*) but when I try it says "operation not permitted" (even as root).

I tried :

```
-chmod ugo+w
-chmod ugo+w
```

`-csrutil disable` (*this one says "csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS.*"

```
-chown root /usr/bin/openssl -R
-chmod 777 /usr/bin/openssl -R
```

please help !

Comment: you should have write permissions in /usr/bin to be able to rename the file

Comment: I forgot to precise that I tried all commands below with /usr/bin and /usr

Comment: Let me say it again: you need permissions to the directory, not the file. The filename IMHO is stored in to the directory record. If you exec ls -ld /usr/bin and you do not see yourself as owner or you are part of group or have 777 permissions you are not able to rename a file in this directory

Comment: let me say it again : I tried to get permissions on directories /usr/bin and /usr

Comment: only root and owner can change the permissions of files and folders.

Have you try to rename with command like: sudo mv filename new_filename

Comment: yes I tried with that too (sorry I forgot to precise it again)

Comment: What kind of error you get when you execute sudo mv ...... And have you try just to copy current openssl executable, then update and use this one you want?

Comment: use `csrutil`.  As the error message you received indicates, you need to reboot to recovery mode (Cmd-R during power up), run `csrutil disable`, and then reboot again.

Comment: works, thanks a lot ! I didn't want to use this solution first (cause I was affraid of consequences if I miss something) but it is ok ^^ file is renamed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply can be done following this steps:

1. Boot your Mac in recovery mode (with holding `Command+R`);
2. Check the status: `csrutil status` (System Integrity Protection (SIP));
3. To disable protection run the following command: `csrutil disable`;
4. Reboot the system again.

P.S. If you decide you want to enable SIP later, return to the recovery environment and run the following command: `csrutil enable` and reboot the system.